# How do you combine raspberry pi python code of 2 csv files?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

we are sending a weather ballon to space with a raspberry pi sense hat and rasp pi camera V2 we have the code written to save to file

This is the code to take pictures

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()

camera.start_preview(alpha=200)
camera.rotation = 180

for i in range(3):

    sleep(5)
    
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image%s.jpg' % i)

camera.stop_preview()
```

and this is the code to sense the enviroment

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
sense=SenseHat()

file = open("Datafile.csv","a")

file.write("Time, Humidity, Temperature, Pressure")

print ("Time, Humidity, Temperature, Pressure")

for n in range(60 ):
    humidity = sense.get_humidity()
    humidity = round(humidity, 2)
    
    file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
    file.write(",") 
    file.write(str(humidity))
    file.write("/n")

    temperature = sense.get_temperature()
    temperature = round(temperature, 2)
    
    print (time.strftime('%X'),humidity)
    
    file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
    file.write(",") 
    file.write(str(temperature))
    file.write("/n")
    
    temperature = sense.get_temperature()
    temperature = round(temperature, 2)
    
    print (time.strftime('%X'),temperature)
    
    pressure = sense.get_pressure()
    pressure = round(pressure, 2)
    
    file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
    file.write(",") 
    file.write(str(pressure))
    file.write("\n")
    
    print (time.strftime('%X'),pressure)
    time.sleep(1)

file.close()
```

Both work we are just now trying to combine them.  Please help!!

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you running into?

Comment: I put both together and finding the senses is fine but it completely doesn't acknowledge the camera code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is take the code for each action taking a photo and collecting sensor data and create a function for each. Then you could use a single loop that calls each function. I quickly put together an example of how this could look with your code that uses a single main loop to collect a photo about every 5 seconds and sensor data about every second.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time


def initialize_camera():
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.start_preview(alpha=200)
    camera.rotation = 180
    return camera


def capture_picture(camera, img_number):
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image%s.jpg' % img_number)


def capture_sensor_data(sense, file):
    humidity = sense.get_humidity()
    humidity = round(humidity, 2)

    file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
    file.write(",")
    file.write(str(humidity))
    file.write("/n")

    temperature = sense.get_temperature()
    temperature = round(temperature, 2)

    print(time.strftime('%X'), humidity)

    file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
    file.write(",")
    file.write(str(temperature))
    file.write("/n")

    temperature = sense.get_temperature()
    temperature = round(temperature, 2)

    print(time.strftime('%X'), temperature)

    pressure = sense.get_pressure()
    pressure = round(pressure, 2)

    file.write(time.strftime('%X'))
    file.write(",")
    file.write(str(pressure))
    file.write("\n")

    print(time.strftime('%X'), pressure)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    camera = initialize_camera()
    sense = SenseHat()

    with open("Datafile.csv", "a") as file:
        file.write("Time, Humidity, Temperature, Pressure")
        print("Time, Humidity, Temperature, Pressure")

        photo_num = 1

        for i in range(60):
            if i % 5 == 0:
                capture_picture(camera, photo_num)
                photo_num += 1

            capture_sensor_data(sense, file)
            time.sleep(1)

        camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: I was hopeful, but it didn't work.

Comment: what kind of errors or issues occurred when you tried it?

Comment: The big error that came up was "if __name__ == '__main__': " But you gave me an idea of how to combine the two so I'm making my own functions to execute it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here is a good post about "if __name__ == '__main__'" and what it does in python and why it is used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do It may not be the right thing to use for this application